# Checking if first item of a list of list exists in first item of another list of list

Tags: python, list

for example.

lets consider this is my list

```
A = [["A1",0],["B1",0],["C1",1],["D1",3]]
```

and this is the list which i wanna compare it with

```
B = [["C1",2],["E1",3]]
```

How do i compare only first index of each list inside the list?. for ex.
Searching if first index of any list in list A exists at first index of any list inside List B?

I want to insert all the items from B to A that doesn't have the same first index for any list. so i don't wanna insert ["C1",2] because C1 already exist in list A but ["C1",2] doesn't but i don't care about the second index value.

I hope i was able to explain this problem.

Comment: this looks like a job better suited for a dictionary

Comment: @Copperfield Sorry, just started learning python today, eventually i will get to dictionaries too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any kind of automated way of doing this, but you can easily implement it yourself.

```
for l in B:
    first = l[0]
    found = False
    for m in A:
        if m[0] == first
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        A.append(l)
```

Comment: Thanks man! i was almost on my way to achieving this and was integrating a found like variable in my method when your answer popped up. Glad to know i was going in right direction :-)

Comment: Also if i don't use the first variable and directly compare it with l[0] it won't make a difference right?. edit: spoilers.it won't

Comment: The only difference is in efficiency.  If you get rid of `first`, you're performing the indexing operation over and over again.  But I can imagine that for most applications the difference would not be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is in option for you but it would be much easier to use dictionaries here:

```
A = {"A1":0,"B1":0,"C1":1,"D1":3}
B = {"C1":2,"E1":3}
for B_key in B.keys():
    if not B_key in A.keys():
        A[B_key] = B[B_key]
```

Comment: you don't need to explicitly call .keys(), dictionaries naturally iterate over its keys and membership testing is on keys too, so no need call .keys() there either

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
A = [["A1",0],["B1",0],["C1",1],["D1",3]]
B = [["C1",2],["E1",3]]

import operator
A_indexes = set(map(operator.itemgetter(0), A)) # Create a set of indexes for O(1) lookup

# Add to A each item that is present in B but not in indexes.
# At the same time, add in indexes.
A.extend(
    A_indexes.add(item[0]) or item for item in B
    if item[0] not in A_indexes)
```

It's the most efficient solution by far. All others are O(n^2).

If you don't care about order, this is also viable:

```
A = [["A1",0],["B1",0],["C1",1],["D1",3]]
B = [["C1",2],["E1",3]]

import itertools
A = list(dict(itertools.chain(B, A)).items())
```

Comment: the OP is new to python, maybe you should at explanation for the `or` part in the extend

Comment: @Copperfield lol, was just editing JS in between. Problems of being multi-lingual :P
Either case, he already has an accepted answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
>>> A = [["A1",0],["B1",0],["C1",1],["D1",3]]
>>> B = [["C1",2],["E1",3]]
>>>
>>> for item in B:
...     if item[0] not in [item_a[0] for item_a in A]:
...             A.append(item)
...
>>> A
[['A1', 0], ['B1', 0], ['C1', 1], ['D1', 3], ['E1', 3]]
```

Comment: It's meant to modify A, not B!

Comment: for the check, there is no need to create a whole new list, you can use a generator expression for the same result without wasting space or with an adequate use of `any`

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code, it work's but i don't think if it's efficient.

```
for a in range(0, len(A)):
    for b in range(0, len(B)):
        if B[b][0] == A[a][0]:
            print B[b]
```

And the result of this code is

```
['C1', 2]
```

Comment: i thought finding the matches is the hard part. so i didn't write the whole code and just something so he could work a bit on it and make it what he wants.